Error when run in react native Android after installed react-native-screens
I already installed react-native-screens successfully(npm install react-native-screens),but,run the app (metro) i get this error(npm run android) :


how to run android app successfully

i want to make a TabBar


Can you share the output of running native-doctor?

thank you for your answer sincerely
I insert a picture on the question about the output of running native-doctor

It seems like things relating to Android are not configured properly. Have you tried fixing those?

before install react-native-screens， It runs successfully ，i want to make a TabBar，so i installed  react-native-screens ，Then i get an error   ；I insert a new picture on the question about my code
